# Find Engel Curve with a Cobb-Douglas

Tags: microeconomics, cobb-douglas

I have $U(x,y)=xy$, $p_1=4$ and $p_2=1$. Income is unknown. Where do I start?

Comment: Use the fact that slope of IC equals slope of the budget line in equilibrium and then use the budget equation to get the demand as a function of income and that's your Engel curve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deriving Equation for Engel Curve](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/deriving-equation-for-engel-curve)

Comment: Start by reading your book chapter on Engel curves.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1, as it were, would be to write down the expenditure function (4x+y).  Next, think about what happens if income is $0; the optimal choices of x and y are easy, as only (0,0) can be consumed. Then ask "what happens as income increases?" and you're off to the races!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would attack this is to solve the utility function $u(x,y)=xy$ subject to the budget constraint: $4x+y=m$. This is using Lagrange method
It turns out that $x=m/8$ and $y=m/2$.

The Engel curve show the relationship between income and the quantity of the good demanded, so substitute values for $m$ and find the corresponding $x$ or $y$ demanded and plot the Engel curve for good x or good y.